# Objective C Reading Complete File To String

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to make a file manager for iOS (my code has an exploit built in so it works).

The main code for my application is written in Swift and the code for running the exploit and reading files is written in Objecive-C.

This is the code I'm currently using in Objective-C:

```
NSString* readFile(NSString* file) {
    char* buffer;
    long lSize;
    char* convertedFileName = [file UTF8String];
    char* newFileName = deleteLastChar(convertedFileName); >> removes last / from path
    char ch;
    FILE *fp=fopen(newFileName, "r");
    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    buffer = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , fp) )
        fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    printf(buffer);

    fclose(fp);
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buffer];
}
```

And this is the code for Swift:

```
func openFile(file: String) {
    let fileContents = readFile(file)

    print(fileContents) >> outputs nil
}
```

This is an example of a file I'm trying to open (plist file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>canvas_height</key>
<integer>1136</integer>
<key>canvas_width</key>
<integer>640</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is what the printf in the Objective-C code returns:

```
bplist00\322]canvas_height\canvas_width\240\332
(+
```

And Swift says the string is nil

The file is being read but there is still something wrong. Any ideas on how to fix this or a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why are you using such code to read a file? There are much better and simpler ways to load a file into a String in Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy asks why so much code. Maybe the exploit requires it... (lower level code)? What are the SO ethics here in answering this Q? Just wondering...

Comment: agreed with @rmaddy u should use some xml reader wrapper and be done with it

Comment: Is the plist file you are try to read in plain text or compressed format? The latter can happen accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we use the simpler way like this:

```objectivec
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"<paht/to/file>"
                     enconding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error: &error];
```

Comment: Please read the whole question and the comments, not just the title. This answer doesn't really apply to the OP's issue. Besides that, the OP never responded to any comments and hasn't been on SO in over 3 years.